# Android application stays black but continues to work

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm developing an application using the Android SDK in Eclipse. In some specific cases when I go to the settings screen and then go back to the main Activity, the screen stays black. The application is still fully functional, the buttons are still working. I know it because there is a "play" button that starts audio and I can also click on a web link from the black screen that opens in the browser. The log of the OS shows some errors that seems to be related to the OS and not the application:

```
02-09 09:22:20.571: WARN/GraphicBufferMapper(25297): registerBuffer(0x12aad0) failed -14 (Bad address)
02-09 09:22:20.571: WARN/Surface(25297): registerBuffer(...) failed -14 (Bad address)
02-09 09:22:20.571: ERROR/Surface(25297): getBufferLocked(0, 00000033) failed (Bad address)
02-09 09:22:20.571: ERROR/Surface(25297): dequeueBuffer failed (Bad address)
02-09 09:22:20.586: ERROR/ViewRoot(25297): IllegalArgumentException locking surface
02-09 09:22:20.586: ERROR/ViewRoot(25297): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
02-09 09:22:20.586: ERROR/ViewRoot(25297):     at android.view.Surface.lockCanvasNative(Native Method)
02-09 09:22:20.586: ERROR/ViewRoot(25297):     at android.view.Surface.lockCanvas(Surface.java:314)
02-09 09:22:20.586: ERROR/ViewRoot(25297):     at android.view.ViewRoot.draw(ViewRoot.java:1341)
02-09 09:22:20.586: ERROR/ViewRoot(25297):     at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:1163)
02-09 09:22:20.586: ERROR/ViewRoot(25297):     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1727)
02-09 09:22:20.586: ERROR/ViewRoot(25297):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-09 09:22:20.586: ERROR/ViewRoot(25297):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
02-09 09:22:20.586: ERROR/ViewRoot(25297):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
02-09 09:22:20.586: ERROR/ViewRoot(25297):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-09 09:22:20.586: ERROR/ViewRoot(25297):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
02-09 09:22:20.586: ERROR/ViewRoot(25297):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
02-09 09:22:20.586: ERROR/ViewRoot(25297):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
02-09 09:22:20.586: ERROR/ViewRoot(25297):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Anyone has encountered this issue before?

Comment: Were you able to find the root cause for this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, but when I use was creating a widget for my app and when user clicked on a button on it, the button appeared in big (in a new Activity with FrameLayout) and when I clicked the back button, I got the same black screen. Solution was to add `finish()` to the end of the `onCreate()` method.